# Nullpointer Exception in Unit Test

Tags: java, unit-testing, grails, groovy

I'm working on a Groovy Grails application and specifically at the moment I'm working on a service that will allow me to generate PLSQL. I'm having some issues however with working out how to solve this Null pointer exception with my unit test below.

Here is the error message:

java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.bt.mlp.TemplatingService.$tt__buildTemplateStepSql(TemplatingService.groovy:59)                        at com.bt.mlp.TemplatingServiceSpec.Can create PLSQL for             TemplateStep(TemplatingServiceSpec.groovy:113)

If I click on the first `NullPointer` it takes me to `def result =`  in the second block of code.

If I click on the second `NullPointer` it takes me to `def result = service.buildTemplateStepSql(templateStep)` in the unit test.

Unit Test:

```
void "Can create PLSQL for TemplateStep" () {
    setup:
        createTemplateStep()
        def validString =
        """

            select sysid into v_mt_sysid from template where name = 'Add FASTE 60 Card';
            MLP_TEMPLATE_CP.TEMPLATE_STEPS_INS(IN_MT_SYSID => v_mt_sysid
            ,IN_STEP => 'step'
            ,IN_VALIDATION_PROCEDURE => 'Procedure'
            ,IN_ACTION_PROCEDURE => 'MLP_CARD_INFILL'
            ,IN_TRANSACTION_TABLE => 'Table'
            ,IN_DISPLAY_LABLE => 'Capture plan inputs'
            ,IN_WINDOW_LABLE => 'Capture plan inputs'
            ,IN_CANCEL_PROCEDURE => 'Cancel Procedure'
            ,IN_END_PLAN_PHASE => 'Designed'
            ,IN_MFOUT_FLAG => 'N'
            ,IN_STEP_SEQ => 1
            ,IN_SWF_NAME => 'Name'
            ,OUT_TS_SYSID => v_ts_sysid );        

        """
        when:
            def templateStep = TemplateStep.findByStep("step")
            def result = service.buildTemplateStepSql(templateStep)
        then:
            result == validString   

}
```

Code being tested:

```
def buildTemplateStepSql(TemplateStep templateStep) {
    println templateStep
    def result =
    """

            select sysid into v_mt_sysid from template where name = 'Add FASTE 60 Card';
            MLP_TEMPLATE_CP.TEMPLATE_STEPS_INS(IN_MT_SYSID => v_mt_sysid
            ,IN_STEP => '${templateStep.step}'
            ,IN_VALIDATION_PROCEDURE => '${templateStep.validationProcedure}'
            ,IN_ACTION_PROCEDURE => '${templateStep.actionProcedure}'
            ,IN_TRANSACTION_TABLE => '${templateStep.transactionTable}'
            ,IN_DISPLAY_LABLE => '${templateStep.displayLable}'
            ,IN_WINDOW_LABLE => '${templateStep.windowLable}'
            ,IN_CANCEL_PROCEDURE => '${templateStep.cancelProcedure}'
            ,IN_END_PLAN_PHASE => '${templateStep.endPlanPhase}'
            ,IN_MFOUT_FLAG => '${templateStep.mfOutFlag}'
            ,IN_STEP_SEQ => '${templateStep.stepSeq}'
            ,IN_SWF_NAME => '${templateStep.swfName}'
            ,OUT_TS_SYSID => v_ts_sysid );

    """

    return result

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is `service` from the first block?

Comment: I can't tell for sure without knowing which line is 59, but the most likely cause of an NPE in that service method would be if `templateStep` is null, which in turn suggests `findByStep` didn't find anything.

Comment: @curiosu It's referring to the service class I created which the second block is sitting in.

Comment: @IanRoberts Line 59 is referring to 'def result =' in the 2nd block of code. Ok that makes sense I'll look into this further.